# Getting first (or a specific) td in BeautifulSoup with no class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have one of those nightmare tables with no class given for the tr and td tags.

A sample page is here: https://system.gotsport.com/org_event/events/1271/schedules?age=19&gender=m

(You'll see in the code below that I'm getting multiple pages, but that's not the problem.)

I want the *team* name (nothing else) from each bracket. The output should be:

> OCYS
> FL Rush
> Jacksonville FC
> Atlanta United
> SSA
> Miami Rush Kendall SC
> IMG
> Tampa Bay United
> etc.

I've been able to get *every* td in the specified tables. But every attempt to use `[0]` to get the first `td` of every row gives me an "index out of range" error.

The code is:

```
import requests
import csv 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

batch_size = 2
urls = ['https://system.gotsport.com/org_event/events/1271/schedules?age=19&gender=m', 'https://system.gotsport.com/org_event/events/1271/schedules?age=17&gender=m']

# iterate through urls
for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")



# iterate through leagues and teams
    leagues = soup.find_all('table', class_='table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed')
    for league in leagues:
        row = ''
        rows = league.find_all('tr')
        for row in rows:
            team = row.find_all('td')
            teamName = team[0].text.strip()    
            print(teamName)
```

After a couple of hours of work, I feel like I'm just one syntax change away from getting this right. Yes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a CSS Selector `nth-of-type(n)`. It works for both links:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://system.gotsport.com/org_event/events/1271/schedules?age=19&gender=m"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

for tag in soup.select(".small-margin-bottom td:nth-of-type(1)"):
    print(tag.text.strip())
```

Output:

```
OCYS
FL Rush
Jacksonville FC
Atlanta United
SSA
...
...
Real Salt Lake U19
Real Colorado
Empire United Soccer Academy
```

Comment: BEAUTIFUL! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Each bracket corresponds to one "panel", and each panel has two rows, the first of which contains the first table of all teams in the match tables.

```
def main():

    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    url = "https://system.gotsport.com/org_event/events/1271/schedules?age=19&gender=m"

    response = requests.get(url)
    response.raise_for_status()
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

    for panel in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "panel-body"}):
        for row in panel.find("tbody").find_all("tr"):
            print(row.find("td").text.strip())
    
    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
OCYS
FL Rush
Jacksonville FC
Atlanta United
SSA
Miami Rush Kendall SC
IMG
Tampa Bay United
Weston FC
Chargers SC
South Florida FA
Solar SC
RISE SC
...
```

Comment: Thanks - that worked. 

At some point, I'll do some studying and figure out *how* it works. I'm still a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the header of the table, which contains `th` elements instead of `td` elements. It leads to the index of range error, when you try to retrieve first element from an empty list. Try to add check for the length of the `td`:

```
for row in rows:
    team = row.find_all('td')
    if(len(team) > 0):
        teamName = team[0].text.strip()    
        print(teamName)
```

It should print you the team names.